# How do I can filter pandas DataFrame by slice of column value

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a following Dataframe:

```py
    ter_id          shstr   value
6   2018002000000   201     1740.0
7   2018002000000   201     10759.0
8   2018002000002   201     2.0
```

How do I can filter out rows with last six symbols of `ter_id` is zeroes? That is desired output is:

```py
    ter_id          shstr   value
8   2018002000002   201     2.0
```

I made a boolean function

```py
def is_total(ter_id: str) -> bool:
    if ter_id[:-6] == "000000":
        return True
    return False
```

But it usage fail with error:

```
dataset.filter(is_total(dataset.ter_id))
...
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Pandas version is 1.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For filtering a dataframe based on column values, there is rarely a reason to write your own function. You can pass the conditions as a boolean mask into df.loc[] (assuming your DataFrame is named df).

```
df = df.loc[df["ter_id"].str[-6:] != "000000"]
```

Comment: I checked to make sure no one had that answer before I posted. I wrote up this answer because your answer did not have that. It retooled OP's function instead of suggesting to use boolean masking, which is why I wrote this answer in the first place.

Comment: I had even refreshed before posting to make sure my answer wasn't already posted and saw nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Change indexing for last `6` values by `[-6:]` and get all non matched rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = dataset[dataset.ter_id.str[-6:] != "000000"]
print (df)
          ter_id shstr value
8  2018002000002   201   2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
df[~(df.ter_id%1000000==0)]
Out[256]: 
          ter_id  shstr  value
8  2018002000002    201    2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, what comes to my mind is that you should first convert the column (ter_id) to string. Then use .contains method on the whole column

```py
df_filtered = df[~df.ter_id.str.contains("000000")].copy()
```

`df` is your dataframe name. I used `copy()` function to surpress warnings. Let me know if this helps....

P.S. You can put any string instead of zeros.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a Python function, you can just use:

```
dataset[dataset['ter_id'].str.slice(-6) != '000000']
```